# fabric8 kubernetes client watch vs SharedIndexInformer

Tags: kubernetes, fabric8

What is difference between fabric8 kubernetes client watch and SharedIndexInformer. What is the advantage of using SharedIndexInformer over watch.

Comment: There are various blogposts on internet about Informers vs Watch. I've written a blogpost about this from fabric8 perspective: https://rohaan.medium.com/introduction-to-fabric8-kubernetes-java-client-informer-api-b945082d69af

Comment: Np, please read it whenever you find time. If it's still not clear, I would try to write a detailed answer

Comment: I went through it and its very clear @RohanKumar. Testing with Watch first with fabric8 but trying to let the Watch receive the events as part of a Runnable thread inside the application. Meaning, when the application begins, watch is run on a thread but issues were found with previous K8s client where the session was lost. So trying to test it with fabric8 and see what works best. I was curious to find the advantages of SharedIndexFormer. I will test and compare. Thank you!

Comment: ohk, I see. Please feel free to reach out to us via Github issue or Gitter channel in case you have any queries.

Comment: @RohanKumar, I have tried SharedIndexInformer and it works good. I have a question, does the SharedIndexInformer opens a separate thread using Runnable? I have an application when it starts, it starts the watch in a separate thread if I use Runnable. If I don't use, the program only watches and doesn't allow any other flow like communicating with other applications. When I tested with SharedIndexInformer, I observed that it didn't require a separate Runnable thread. It was watching and also able to receive and forward messages other applications. Do you have any idea on this?

Comment: Hi, yes you're right. SharedInformer involves a bunch of threads. You can look into the code to get better idea: https://github.com/fabric8io/kubernetes-client/blob/master/kubernetes-client/src/main/java/io/fabric8/kubernetes/client/informers/impl/DefaultSharedIndexInformer.java

Comment: @RohanKumar, https://rohaan.medium.com/introduction-to-fabric8-kubernetes-java-client-informer-api-b945082d69af, I have implemented using the Informer. The resync period keeps updating last two updates especially it keeps calling onUpdate method. What is the importance of resync? I didn't see other methods without it so that I can get only events when the pod is added/modified/deleted.

Comment: A resync plays back all the events held in informer internal cache. You should  set it more than a few minutes but less than a few hours

Comment: @RohanKumar, can I set it to zero and not get any play back of events?

Comment: Umm, no. I don't think it's possible. Resync period is quite important as it helps control how often you want to reconcile. Please checkout this thread which might help you in getting a better idea: https://groups.google.com/g/kubernetes-sig-api-machinery/c/PbSCXdLDno0

Comment: Let's move this discussion to Fabric8 Chat: https://gitter.im/fabric8io/kubernetes-client